# Regex look ahead to find if character exists in next n(5) characters

Tags: regex

Given the string...

```
2010-01-21DD2010-01-21XX2010-01-21ND2010-01-2104XN
```

..., I would like to detect the last two date-char combinations.

I have tried `(2010-01-21(?=NN)[A-Z]{2})`, but this only works if both are `N`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check if the letter `N` follows, you could use the following.

```
[\d-]+(?=[A-Z]{0,5}N)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gQ1xJ3/5)

Comment: Thank you for you fast answer, i was aware i could do it like that, but sometimes there may be up to 6 characters ie 2010-01-2104XNTYUI, if this is the only way i will have to code to suit. I just wondered if they was another way that could more easily suit my task many Thanks Tim

Comment: YEs so for given date 2010-01-21, i want to check up to the next 6 chars to see if it contains an N in any of them locations

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to check 1-*n* letters must contain at least 1 'N'

```
 # [\d-]+[A-Z]{1,6}(?<=N)

 [\d-]+            # Digits or dashes
 [A-Z]{1,6}        # 1 to 6 characters
 (?<= N )          # Must have found 'N' within 1-6 letters
                   # [A-Z]*  Optionally grab the rest of trailing letters
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for the character `N` in the following 5 characters, you can use `(?=.{0,4}N)`.

That is, "followed by up to 4 characters and `N`".

In your case, it looks like you want to look in the next 2 characters. This would be `(?=.{0,1}N)`, which is equivalent to `(?=.?N)`.

Comment: I think he's trying to get it as part of the match. `[A-Z]{0,4}N` or it would fail if no match.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use alternatives, e.g. `(N[A-Z]|[A-Z]N)`?

Comment: Thank you for you fast answer, i was aware i could do it like that, but sometimes there may be up to 6 characters ie 2010-01-2104XNTYUI, if this is the only way i will have to code to suit. I just wondered if they was another way that could more easily suit my task many Thanks Tim

Comment: If the number of the letters is not limited and 'N' can be not only in the first two positions, may something simple like `[A-Z]*N[A-Z]*` help?